# Generate/use images similar to those on Github's Explore Showcases

Tags: svg, github

I noticed some nice images on Github's Explore Showcases:

[image]

I would like to use something similar on my own application. Is there a library that randomly generates such images? I see they use SVG, but not sure how I can use or even create something similar.

Comment: Last one is a bit like http://www.noupe.com/essentials/freebies-tools-templates/low-poly-trend-six-free-generators-for-backgrounds-and-images-84108.html

Comment: It isn't the same, but it's a great library I wasn't aware of! Thank you. You should submit this as an answer, it's pretty close and damn nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented before, the last picture can be generated by a [number of background generators](http://www.noupe.com/essentials/freebies-tools-templates/low-poly-trend-six-free-generators-for-backgrounds-and-images-84108.html) like:

- [Trianglify](http://qrohlf.com/trianglify/),
- [Triangulation/](http://snorpey.github.io/triangulation/),
- [I love triangle](http://somestuff.ru/filter/HTML5/I),
- [DMesh](http://dmesh.thedofl.com/),
- [image-triangulator](http://www.conceptfarm.ca/2013/portfolio/image-triangulator/),
- [delaunay-triangulations/](http://labs.vieron.net/delaunay-triangulations/).

All are capable to export the resulting picture as SVG.
And then you have javascript libraries:

- [`snapsvg.io`](http://snapsvg.io/),
- [seenjs.io](http://seenjs.io/).